# Firing click event in Bookmarklet ends up where Asp.Net throwing Null Reference exception

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer-9

For testing purposes i have to fill certain inputs in a page and Submit it and validate the values, Since it is a repetitive task i have automated entering the inputs and Submitting it through a Simple JS file. The problem is i have to run it in Internet Explorer 9 where the script runs fine when i run it from the console, but when i convert it to a Bookmarklet the Click event generates an Null reference error.

Assume a code simple as `$("#sampleElement")[0].click();` The button is clicked and the corresponding event listener is fired when executed from the console but throws error when executed from a bookmarklet.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that jQuery is loaded and usable when the Bookmarklet code is executed, and also that the DOM is ready and complete. To test (from a Bookmarklet):

```
if (typeof $ === 'undefined')
    alert('jQuery not available');
else if ($("#sampleElement").length === 0)
    alert('#sampleElement not available');
```